# Factorial using imperative-style programming

Tags: haskell, imperative-programming

I have the following code:

```
while :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
while test body =
  do b <- test
     if b
       then do {body ; while test body}  -- same-line syntax for do
       else return ()
```

I need to implement the factorial function using imperative-style programming. what I have to do is to create and initialize variables using `newIORef`, modify their values using a while loop with `readIORef` and `writeIORef`, then have the `IO` action return a pair consisting of the input `n` and the final result.

This is what I have done so far:

```
fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do r <- newIORef n --initialize variable
            while
              (do {v <- readIORef n; n})
              (do {v <- readIORef r; writeIORef (...)) --modify the value (?)
            readIORef r
```

This is my attempt to write the factorial function. This is obviously does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: imperative really? ... wow you got a naughty teacher there ... anywyay I think it's easier for you if you add another *variable* - use two: an *accumulator* where you multiply up the result and a *index* that you count up to `n` (simulate a `for` loop with the `while`)

Comment: @Carsten Actually, I find this to be a nice exercise to check if someone knows how to use `IORef`s and understands `IO`. Sure, the produced code is expected to be hard to read, and quite unidiomatic. This is definitely not an exercise about elegance ;-)

Comment: hey whatever helps you learn ... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe it's time to give you some working version:

```
fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do
  i <- newIORef 1
  acc <- newIORef 1
  while (lessOrEqualN i) (step i acc)
  acc' <- readIORef acc
  return $ (n, acc')
  where
     lessOrEqualN iRef = do
       i' <- readIORef iRef
       return $ i' <= n
     step iRef accRef = do
       i' <- readIORef iRef
       acc' <- readIORef accRef
       writeIORef accRef (acc' * i')
       writeIORef iRef (i'+1)
```

as you can see I used an *loop* reference `i` and an *accumulator* reference `acc` always reading, writing the changing values.

To make this (hopefully) a *bit* more readable I extracted the `test` and the `body` of the `while` into `lessOrEqualN` and `step`.

---

Of course there are easier ways to do this (`modifyIORef`) but I guess you have to use those.

---

PS: you play with it a bit - maybe you want to handle negative values differently or whatever

---

this might be a bit cleaner (putting both *mutables* into the same ref):

```
fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do
  ref <- newIORef (1,1)
  while (lessOrEqualN ref) (step ref)
  (_,acc) <- readIORef ref
  return $ (n, acc)
  where
     lessOrEqualN ref = do
       (i,_) <- readIORef ref
       return $ i <= n
     step ref = do
       (i,acc) <- readIORef ref
       writeIORef ref (i+1, acc * i)
```

Comment: And the answer is, of course, "basically the same as the usual version, but much more complicated for no reason".

Comment: @ReinHenrichs ? right now I really have no clue what you are getting at - but I have the feeling I did something wrong !(?)

Comment: No, your solution seems fine (given the constraints), it's just that it's a ridiculous problem statement. I don't understand why someone would think that this is a good exercise.

Comment: So this is imperative Haskell code... it makes me glad that I switched to Haskell.

Comment: I wasn't! I was just trying to point out that *any* answer would necessarily be convoluted because the question asks for a convoluted answer. It's basically "write a factorial function but add in a lot of indirection by using IORefs for no reason".

Comment: I'm just kidding ... and I understand perfectly well ... I was just reacting to AJ's comment ... and I probably should just shut up - and so I will ;)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I do think this _is_ a good exercise, if the point is learning how `IORef`s work -- even if the solution is horrible, especially when compared with pure ones. It's a matter of personal taste though.

Comment: @chi It might use IORefs, but I don't think it motivates them at all, which for me is an essential part of an effective exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I think Carsten's answer can be made a bit cleaner like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef

fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do
  counter <- newIORef 1
  result <- newIORef 1
  while (fmap (<=n) (readIORef counter)) $ do
    i <- postIncrement counter
    modifyIORef result (*i)
  fmap (n,) (readIORef result)

while :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
while test body =
  do b <- test
     if b
       then do {body ; while test body}  -- same-line syntax for do
       else return ()

postIncrement :: Enum a => IORef a -> IO a
postIncrement ref = do
  result <- readIORef ref
  modifyIORef ref succ
  return result
```

What I'm doing here is:

1. Using `modifyIORef` to cut down on the number of paired `readIORef`/`writeIORef` calls.
2. Using `fmap` to reduce the need for auxiliary functions to test the contents of an `IORef`.
3. Write a generic, reusable `postIncrement` function and use that to shorten `fact` further.

But frankly, I think your instructor's insistence that you use this `while` function is a bit silly.  It doesn't make for clean code.  If I was told to write an imperative factorial with `IORef` I'd first write this, just using the `forM_` loop from the library:

```
factorial :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
factorial n = do
  result <- newIORef 1
  forM_ [2..n] $ \i -> do
    modifyIORef result (*i)
  fmap (n,) (readIORef result)
```

And that's because I was too dumb to remember `replicateM_ :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m ()` right away...